# Calendar class java

Tags: java, calendar

I am setting the value to be 23 January 2009, but when I ask for month it returns '2'
Here is my code:

```
Calendar calendar=GregorianCalendar.getInstance();  
calendar.set(2009,01,23);  
calendar.getTime();  
System.out.println(calendar.MONTH);
```

Please help! I expect the first output to be 1, not 2!

Comment: ...and a good IDE should point it out...

Comment: The question is already answered, so I can just tell you to try http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Calendar.MONTH` is a constant. It's used to indicate that you want the month field, using `calendar.get()`:

```
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
```

Answer (score 4):

Months are 0-based in `Calendar`, you must write:

```
calendar.set(2009, 0, 23);
```

...or better, to avoid confusion:

```
calendar.set(2009, Calendar.JANUARY, 23);
```

Comment: @does not help! still output is 2

Comment: @TimeToCodeTheRoad: see *JB Nizet*'s answer, you actually have **two** bugs in your code :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
```

get the month of the currently set date in your calendar instance. Calendar.MONTH (which you accessed via the instance) is just a constant which tells the get() to return the month.

See JavaDoc for more information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html